# How do I know which linear fit is better?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, experimental-physics, harmonic-oscillator, error-analysis, data-analysis

Let's say we have a simple mass/string harmonic oscillator. Measuring the period of the movement, I can calculate the angular frequency. Knowing that

$$\omega = \sqrt{\frac{k}{m}} \qquad \text{and} \qquad T = \frac{2\pi}{\omega}$$

we can come to two functions:

$$\omega^2 = \frac{1}{m} \cdot k \qquad \text{and} \qquad m = \frac{T^2}{4 \pi^2} \cdot k$$

which is basically the same function expressing $\omega$ in a different way. Both relations are linear with $k$.

In order to calculate $k$, I used a linear fit.  I made two plots, with $ω^2$ on the $y$ axis and $1/m$ on the $x$ axis in the first plot, and $m$ on the y axis and $T^2/4π^2$ on the $x$ axis in the second plot.  But these two plots gave me completely different results, with a difference of almost 50%. How do I know which one is correct and why did this happen?

Data used:

```
T (s)  0.8283 0.9622 1.0912 1.1195 1.2896
m (kg) 0.02   0.03   0.04   0.05.  0.06
```

Comment: Your raw data is measured in terms of $T$ and $m$, so one would think that your linear fit would be in terms of those variables too.  Why would you want to "massage" the data in order to plot in terms of $\omega ^2$ and $\frac {1}{m}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your data is not well modeled by direct proportionality between $m$ and $T^2/4 \pi^2$.  Both of the fits should go through the origin;  but if you naively plot a least-squares linear fit in each case, you'll find a substantial offset for your data:

[image]

You can get better agreement between the two methods by forcing the fit curve to pass through the origin (details on how to do this differ depending on the software you use.)  The agreement is still not great, but it's better.

More broadly, it is not necessarily the case that the slope of the line that minimizes the least-squares distance for the function $y = m x$ will be the same as the slope of the line that minimizes the least-squares distance for the function $(1/x) = m (1/y)$.  This is because a "naïve" least-squares fit assumes uniformly distributed errors on all your data points and negligible errors in the independent variable;  but when you swap the two plots, you swap the roles of the dependent and independent variables and change the sizes of the errors on them.  In general, the best practice in an introductory class would be to take the independent variable to be the one that is measured more precisely (probably the mass, in this case), use error propagation to estimate error bars on each of your measurements of the dependent variable, and perform an appropriately weighted fit on the data.

Answer (score 0):

This is not linearization, it is just expressing $k$ in two different ways. If you choose two random values for $T$ and $m$ you will get two different results. The catch is that $T$ and $m$ are related via $k$, i.e. $k = f(T, m)$ or $k = g(\omega, m)$ and in both cases you should get the same result if you satisfy $\omega = \frac{2\pi}{T}$ and you use the same $m$.

$$f(T,m) = \frac{4\pi^2}{T^2} m , \qquad g(\omega,m) = \omega^2 m$$

In general, if $k_0 = f(T_0,m_0) = g(\omega_0,m_0)$ where $\omega_0=\frac{2\pi}{T_0}$ then

$$f(T_0,m_0+\Delta) = g(\omega_0,m_0+\Delta)$$

$$f(T_0+\Delta,m_0) \neq g(\omega_0+\Delta,m_0)$$

since functions $f$ and $g$ are linear in $m$ for fixed $T_0$ and $\omega_0$, and nonlinear in $T$ and $\omega$ for fixed $m_0$.

---

What it seems to me is that you are confused how come plots $(T,m,f)$ and $(\omega,m,g)$ do not look the same. In order to understand this consider a simpler case:

$$h(x) = x, \qquad z(y) = \frac{1}{y}, \qquad x = \frac{1}{y}$$

It is obvious that $(x,h)$ and $(y,z)$ plots are not the same, although the two functions are the same in $x$. However, $(x,h)$ and $(1/y,z)$ plots are the same, and this is exactly what happens in your case.

Comment: of course, with each point by itself I do get the same result, but the slope of the trendline is different. Shouldn´t this value be k and the same as well?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean. If you ask should $k$ difference be the same for equal increments in $\omega$ and $\T$ the answer is no, since $\omega$ and $T$ are inversely proportional.

Comment: What I did was plot (the two functions seperately) the points calculated and calculate the slope of the trendline. What I understand is that k should be the slope, but the results are different.

Comment: It is beacuse the two functions for $k$ are nonlinear in $T$ and $\omega$.

Comment: To be more specific, the plot is ω2 on the y axis and 1/m on the x axis in the first plot, and m on the y axis and T2/4π2 on the x axis in the second plot.

Comment: Yes, that is the thing! If you put $4\pi^2/T^2$ instead of the $T^2/4\pi^2$ you will get what you expect, ie the same slope.

Comment: Sorry that I don´t understand. The relation between y and x plotted is linear with slope k. I´m not plotting nor T nor ω by itself..

Comment: Let’s simplify this, imagine you have $f(x)=x$ and $g(y)=y$ where $y = 1/x$. Will the plots $(x,f)$ and $(y,g)$ be the same?

Comment: No, the plots are different, but shouldn´t the slope of both functions be 1 although the points are different?

Comment: If the plots are different, why do you expect the slope will be the same? However, in the simplified example the plots $(x,f)$ and $(1/y,g)$ are the same which also means the same slope.

Comment: So in this case, which slope is k? I´m still a bit confused..

Comment: Can you be more specific, what do you mean by "which slope is $k$"? Do you mean what is the slope of $f(T,m)$ with respect to $T$ and slope of $g(\omega,m)$ with respect to $\omega$?

Comment: It might help if you show the plots.